# How do I find a portion of a file path string?

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

Here is what I am trying to do in groovy:

```
def url = "\\data\\aaa\\Service\\111"
def d = url.find("\\data\\aaa\\Service")
```

But `d` is `null`, which according to the documentation means that it cannot find a match.

I have tested without the slashes and it works fine, so I know the problem has something to do with the slashes.

How can I get groovy to find `\\data\\aaa\\Service` in `\\data\\aaa\\Service\\111`?

**Edit:**

This is my issue and attempt so far to solve it:

- `url` comes in as `/data/cpp/Service/111`
- `folder.path` returns `\data\cpp\Service\111\222`

So I was trying to convert `"/"` in url to `"\"` which makes `url = "\data\cpp\Service\111"`

I then need to remove the `url` portion from the whatever `folder.path` returns

Below is a reflection of that effort:

```
def getList(String url) {
    def list = []
    def dir = new File(url)
    url= url.replaceAll("/", "\\\\")
    def d = url.find("\\\\data\\\\aaa\\\\Service")
    dir.eachDirRecurse
        { folder ->
            list << folder.path.replaceAll(url,'')
        }
    return list
}
```

But nothing is getting replaced because it cannot find `url` within `folder.path`.

Comment: Instead of changing "/" slash in URL I change the "\\" slashes in folder.path

Then I removed path from folder.path that matched URL.


    def getFolder(String url) {
            def list = []
            def dir = new File(url)
            dir.eachDirRecurse
                { folder ->
                    list << folder.path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/").replaceAll(url, '')
                }
                return list
        }


Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slashes.  The following will likely work:

`def d = url.find("\\\\data\\\\aaa\\\\Service")`

Comment: @RSM You can be specific in the question in the first attempt so that the effort given by the answerer will be fruitful in first attempt. :)

Comment: Will do nowonwards. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing "/" slash in URL, I change the "\" slashes in whatever is returned by  folder.path

Then I removed URL from folder.path output.

```
def getFolder(String url) {
    def list = []
    def dir = new File(url)
    dir.eachDirRecurse
        { folder ->
            list << folder.path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/").replaceAll(url, '')
        }
        return list
}
```

Thanks for the help.